# Action form route

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to enable reset password but I have troube with configuration so I made my function in controller to do it.

```
Route::post('/reset_password/{email}','MyController@resetPassword');
```

Now, In password.reset and password.email how to route to this /reset_password

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('password.email') }}">

<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('password.request') }}">
```

Comment: Make sure your routes have a `->name()` or `"as" => "..."` setting when trying to use named route function `route("name")`. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#named-routes for more info

Answer (score 0):

Just add a name for routes

```
Route::post('/reset_password/{email}','MyController@resetPassword')
->name('password.email');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to give a name to your route:

```
 Route::post('/reset_password/{email}', 'MyController@resetPassword')
        ->name('password.email');
```

Then in your View:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" 
      action="{{ route('password.email', ['email' => $email]) }}">
```

[Named Routes documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/urls#urls-for-named-routes)

Or you can use [url helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/urls):

Route:

```
 Route::post('/reset_password/{email}', 'MyController@resetPassword');
```

View:

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" 
       action="{{ url('/reset_password/'. $email) }}">
```